# How to use filter with ArrayFormula?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, array-formulas, transpose, google-sheets-query

Im trying to use array formula to list multiple "rows"  without the blank cells not from another area in the sheet.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(FILTER(GE2:HQ2,LEN(GE2:HQ2)),""))
```

Also tried

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(FILTER(GE2:HQ,LEN(GE2:HQ)),""))
```

Neither returns an array effect. Also tried dragging down the formula to expand the whole sheet. Which works, until a form is submitted. Then the cell in that row loses its formula

Link to an example Sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSl8Olx8fYsgROoCU6xLq4M53liT16DgEgtw1RAt0uqpWPosUGZ6aXjBP5UF5pS6y0ZBwAF-8pZrjZR/pubhtml

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:G4),,9^9)), " "))
```

[image]

---

if dataset contains words in cells use:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 SUBSTITUTE(A2:G4, " ", "♥")),,9^9)), " "), "♥", " "))
```

Comment: This work great for the example. However in the actual spreadsheets each cell contains words instead of numbers. This formula splits each word into a separate cell. Ive tried using "," to split the phrases into cells but no luck yet.

Comment: Jml9548, did this solve your issue, or did you still have a problem with the words in your data being split into separate cells?  I know player0 has previously that issue. 
 You could first do an ArrayFormula(Substitute(your data range," ","♦",1,0) to convert all the spaces between words to symbols.  Then his formula is applied, and lastly the "♦" are converted back to spaces.  This can all be included as part of the formula player0 has provided you.  Hope this helps.